# UIResponder.printContent(_:) is not called when tapping Print in navigation item title menu

Tags: uikit

By following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions/3750910-printcontent), in `Info.plist` I have added `UIApplicationSupportsPrintCommand = true`, but when tapping the navigation item's title and selecting Print, `printContent(_:)` is never called. On the other hand, when selecting Move, `move(_:)` is called as expected. What's the problem?

[image]

The issue can be reproduced by using the code below in a newly created Xcode project with the App template.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "asdf"
        navigationItem.documentProperties = UIDocumentProperties(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/asdf"))
        navigationItem.titleMenuProvider = { suggestions in
            return UIMenu(children: suggestions)
        }
    }

    override func move(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("move")
    }
    
    override func printContent(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("printContent")
    }

}
```